# Surviving nether world's Zombie pigmen in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The first time I entered nether I killed a zombie pig man and ever since they have been trying to kill me every time I step into the nether. I am not able to consolidate my position in the nether. Any general tips or ideas to tackle them

Comment: So your question is how to survive (just kill them before they kill you) or how to make them neutral again?

Comment: to make them neutral again

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Minecraft_Noob has got it exactly right. Building 3 blocks up is a perfect way to stop them.

So, since the question is answered, I'm just gonna tell you what **NOT** to do:

1. Try to escape through lava. They are fireproof.
2. Run. Zombie pigmen are very fast, and you could encounter more along the way. Plus, it is only too easy to get lost in the nether...
3. Aggravate them in future. Once they are neutral again, it often isn't worth fighting them again, as all they can give you is rotten flesh, gold nuggets and ingots, and gold swords and helmets. If you are in the nether, you should have at least iron armour, so this isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Build 3 blocks up and slap them with a sword. Can also box yourself in, but I prefer to build 3 blocks up. Recommended to have sound on so they can't sneak up on you though.